# s3 bucket LifecycleConfiguration rule skipped some expired files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3-lifecycle-policy

I added a LifecycleConfiguration Rule to my s3 bucket to expire files after a year. After enabling the rule, every object was given an expiration date and the majority of the files in the bucket with expiration dates in the past were deleted after about a day. However, there are 2 files still in the bucket with expiration dates in the past that were not removed along with the rest. Is there any reason anyone can think of that these 2 files were skipped?

Comment: Might help if you could give the actual timestamps: when the files were created, when you added the rule, etc. Also are the 2 files versioned? Were they ever non-versioned?